# pgfgantt: why is the figure shorter than \textwidth on the right?

Tags: floats, pgfgantt, textwidth

I am no Latex Pro and trying to get the chart below to be exactly `\textwidth` wide, but somehow it is displayed shorter than the text on the right side. I don't understand why the `expand chart=\textwidth` does not work as I expect it to. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Edit: added `\usepackage{showframe}` and `\fbox{` and the picture of my output after 2 compiliations.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe} %Edit: added

\newgeometry{vmargin={15mm}, hmargin={20mm,20mm}}   % set the margins

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
        \begin{figure*}[!htb]
            \centering%
            \fbox{ %Edit: added
            \begin{ganttchart}[%
                y unit chart=.7cm,%
                canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},%
                hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},%
                vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},%
                title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},%
                title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,%
                include title in canvas=false,%
                bar height=0.3,%
                bar label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},%
                bar label node/.append style={left=0.2cm},%
                bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=cyan},%
                group height=0.3,%
                group label node/.append style={left=0.2cm},%
                group label font=\bfseries\small\color{black},%
                group/.append style={draw=none, fill=blue},%
                expand chart=\textwidth,%
                ]{1}{28}%
                \gantttitle[title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and 10pt}]{KW}{1}%
                \gantttitlelist[title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and 10pt}]{9,...,37}{1} \\%
                \ganttgroup{\textbf{WP1:} Activity A}{1}{5} \\%
                \ganttbar{Activity A11}{1}{3} \\%
                \ganttbar{Activity A12}{2}{5} \\%
                \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{20} \ganttnewline[grid]%
                \ganttgroup{\textbf{WP4:} Activity D}{18}{22} \\%
                \ganttbar{Activity A41}{18}{20} \\%
            \end{ganttchart}%
        }%Edit: added
        \caption{Time schedule.}%
        \end{figure*}
    
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This I get with \showframe and an \fbox around the ganttchart environment:

[image: the document produced by code above]

Comment: Simon: counting error perhaps. Your chart is 28 units wide, but in your title line you have 30 entries. One for KW, and then 37-9+1=29 entries with numbers.

Comment: I put a `\fbox` around it and (after two runs) it fit perfectly.  The excess white space is internal to the chart.

Comment: The counting difference was just because I preferred to also have the 37 on top of the last vertical line of the grid, but I tested with and without and it only has a slight effect but does not explain why
1. the \fbox shows the entire chart to be wider than the \showframe and
2. inside the \fbox there is so much whitespace right to the last vertical grid line

Comment: I think `\begin{ganttchart}{1}{28}  \gantttitle{KW}{1}  \gantttitlelist{9,...,37}{1} \\  \end{ganttchart}` illustrates my previous point, and why you should stop the title list at 35 - extra nodes outside the chart area  Unrelated note: an `\fbox` will have some whitespace between it and the content, so for a case like this adding `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}` is useful.